# Execute loop for each cell from active cell

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to move data from column 1 to column 2.

Because the column 2 may have merged cells, I ditched the copy-paste path, hence now following this logic:

1. loop through each cell in column 1
2. assign each cell value to a variable
3. assign variable value to each last blank cell in column 2

This works just fine. However, the start of my range in column 1 varies too.

Is there a way to set instead of `x=range ("A" & i).value` to somewhat like `x = range(Activecell & i).value`? It doesn't seem to work if I do it exactly like this.

```
Sub pastetest()
    Dim x As String

    For i = 1 To 10
        x = Range("A" & i).Value
        Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = x
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't you unmerge the cells on sheet1? that would solve your problem without loops.

Comment: Check if you can use [the alternative to merged cells](https://officemastery.com/_merge-and-centre-better-alternative/). Merged cells in combination with VBA will always drive you nuts. • Eg `ActiveCell.Resize(10).Value = Range("A1:A10").Value` would work but only without merged cells I think.

Comment: If `ActiveCell` is really your starting point, try `x = Activecell.offset(i-1, 0).value`

Comment: A little bit of a clarity -  the code I pasted doesn't account for sheet differences, so to keep things simple I'll just refer to 2 columns on the same sheet. column 1 doesn't have merged cells. column 2 does have merged cells and must stay as is (the formatting is important). I just need to figure out how to execute the loop from the active cell in column 1, rather than top of column.

Comment: @AndreiC Even thought this way is risky... If your current code works, just do as FunThomas said and that's all you need.

Comment: @FunThomas yeah, works, thanks! :)

Comment: @Damian I get to the active cell via code as well (based on a find function), hence I think it should be fine

Comment: @AndreiC if you get it from code you should definetly not use `Select`or `ActiveCell`. There are better ways. The user could click by mistake any other cell and your code would throw errors, or worse, paste things where it shouldn't.

Comment: @damian at the start of my macro the user inputs a variable to find, then the code looks into a database (standardized structure) to find the value and then offsets 2 columns to the right - that's the start of my range for the question I posted, hence the activecell and processing from that point onward. So as long as the user input is correct and the database is set correctly, I'm expecting it to work just fine. I'm sure there's batter ways as you said, but it works at least for now :)